# How to make a generic List Filter in Django using django-filters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to have a `FilterSet` class that allows all of the fields to be filtered as a list.
I was thinking of overriding the default `FilterSet` class of `django-filters` and having the fields be dynamically set as well as setting a method to each one.

So, something like this for example:

```
ModelName_fields = {'names': 'name', 'ids': 'id', 'second_ids': 'second_id'}
class ListFilter(FilterSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self._meta.fields = [field_name for field_name in modelNameHere + '_fields']
        super(FilterSet).__init__(*args)

 class SomeAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin): 
    model = ModelName 
    filterset_class = ListFilter
```

Basically, `ModelName_fields` is a declared constant that maps the query parameter to the field name of the model. In this case, I declare the model on the view as well as the filterset class and in the `__init__` method of the filterset class, I dynamically attach the fields as well as the query parameter name.

In all essence, I just want to make the ListFilter as generic as possible to be used on different views as well.
My question is, is this the correct way or is there some other better way to accomplish this? Also, how can I get the name of the model, which is an attribute of the view class, in the `ListFilter` class?

Comment: I think this https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#automatic-filter-generation-with-model is what you want.